# Vue.js rendering of SVG fragment fails in IE11

Tags: svg, vuejs2, internet-explorer-11

I need to fetch a lot of SVG documents from AWS and I use vue.js to render the content of the SVG. This works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Safari but fails without errors in IE11.

I have created jsFiddle to illustrate my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/dotnetCarpenter/pp7bcLkk/

The raw SVG file can be viewed here and is rendered in IE11: https://napp-siesta-test.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/siesta-demo-mwqxbrqx/uploads/1506688653629/viewer/472.svg

Since I need to set `v-show` and `class` on the SVG, I have a `<svg>` container in my template that I add the SVG string to via `v-html`.
I strip the `<svg>` element from the received SVG document and also resolve the relative paths to fonts, since I'm in-lining the SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed [in this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5310) `v-html` uses `innerHTML` which has no effect on `SVG` element in IE.

Luckily in VueJS 2.6 there was a [workaround added](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/8652).

So for you there are two possible fixes: upgrade VueJS version or use custom render function and construct VNodes for `SVG` content manually.